# Where-Object and Arrays not filtering correctly

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble getting my script to work correctly. 
I have three arrays.  The extensions array does filter correctly.  However my arrays with wildcards are not generating the results I want.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# Read List of Servers from flat file
$data=Get-Content C:\myscripts\admin_servers.txt

# Variables that will be used against search parameter
$extensions = @(".ecc", ".exx", ".ezz", ".vvv")
$wildcards = @("Help_*.txt", "How_*.txt", "Recovery+*")
$exclude = @("help_text.txt", "Lxr*.exx", "help_contents.txt")

# Loop each server one by one and do the following
foreach ($server in $data)
{
    # Search the server E:\ and all subdirectories for the following types of
    # extensions or wildcards.
    Get-ChildItem -path \\$server\e$ -Recurse | Where-Object {
        (($extensions -contains $_.Extension) -or $_.Name -like $wildcards) -and
        $_.Name -notlike $exclude
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_.Name -like $wildcards` is comparing `$_.Name` to an array.  You need to compare `$_.Name` to each value in the array.

Comment: so I would need to add an -or and -and statement for each value?  [0], [1],[2], etc?  There's no way to shortcut that?  I was hoping the array would work instead of having to specify each value within the where clause.

Comment: This works: `($wildcards | % { "help_a.txt" -like $_ }).Contains($true)`.  There may be a more succinct way.  I hard-coded a file name to test it but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own function:

```
function Like-Any {
    param (
        [String]
        $InputString,

        [String[]]
        $Patterns
    )

    foreach ($pattern in $Patterns) {
        if ($InputString -like $pattern) {
            return $true
        }
    }
    $false
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path \\$server\e$ -Recurse | 
Where-Object { `
    (($extensions -contains $_.Extension) -or (Like-Any $_.Name $wildcards)) `
    -and !(Like-Any $_.Name $exclude)}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason.  Works perfectly.  I like the function.  It works just like I was hoping my original script would work.  I just need to understand decipher the verbiage in the function.  I will do some research.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handy with Regular Expressions you can do this with a `-Match` comparison. Replace your `$Wildcards =` and `$Exclude =` lines with:

```
$wildcards = "Help_.*?\.txt|How_.*?\.txt|Recovery\+.*"
$Exclude = "help_text\.txt|Lxr.*?\.exx|help_contents\.txt"
```

And then your `Where-Object` line with:

```
    Where-Object {(($extensions -contains $_.Extension) -or $_.Name -match $wildcards) -and $_.Name -notmatch $exclude}
```

That should do it for you. Explanation for the `$Wildcard =` match available at [this RegEx101 link](https://regex101.com/r/nN4xI0/1).

Comment: This works as well.  I just have no experience in Regular Expressions.  Thanks for the useful reference.  I will take some time to understand it better.

Comment: Using Regular Expressions does take a bit of learning, but they are extremely powerful when trying to parse or match text and patterns, and they're very fast when compared to some other methods. I'm glad you found an answer that works for you!